# How to get XML feed of Google Analytic data with JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, google-api

Is there a way I can get an XML feed of data of my own Google Analytic data, (i.e.

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/my-account/my-data.xml
```

If this was possible, I would then use Google Feed API to read that onto my personal web page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GA Reporting API for Event Tracking to pull this data from GA.  Request it every few hours and store the results, and show the stored result on your pages.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=event_tracking

Comment: There has to be an easier way....especially for users who only want to depend on JavaScript, XML and HTML to pull the data.